# import string/re/sys in python

Tags: python, import

I keep noticing blocks of code starting with import string, import re or import sys.
I know that you must import a module before you can use it.  Is the import based on the object?

Comment: "Is the import based on the object?" I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The import is based on  [what module you want to access the names of](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Python has modules that give the code more functionalities. `import re` gives access to the `re` module which gives RegEx support. If you type `help()` at the Python interpreter and then type modules, it will return a list of all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
```

Will have the effect of adding a `sys` variable to your local namespace (usually at the module level).  Because `sys` is a module with it's own attributes, then you can say `sys.something()`, and Python will be able to reference the local name `sys`, and then the attribute `something`, and then call it `()`.

```
from os.path import join
```

This will look inside the os package, inside the path subpackage, and create a local reference to the `join` function in your namespace.  That way, you can simply refer to it as:

```
join('a', 'b')
```

Suggest you look at a couple of tutorials that cover importing.

Comment: os.path isn't actually a subpackage.